# Making Simultaneous App-to-Phone Calls (Android)

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

We are developing a new app using the sinch voice api to make app-to-phone calls for Android.

We’ve tried the sample project and everything works brilliant except that we can’t make simultaneous calls with the same app. We’ve installed the sample project in 2 different android phones and if that 2 devices try to make a call with sinch at the same time one of them can’t make the call. We’ve tried with different users and even tried to create a production app in the sinch dashboard but nothing worked.

So what can we do to make this work? We have to create an app and generate api keys for every device that we are going to use in order to make simultaneous app-to-phone calls?

Thanks

Comment: The problem was that when your application makes a PSTN call, sinch reserves a sum on your account to make sure you have enough credit to actually pay for the call. If you don’t specify the maximum duration for a call, we reserve 240 minutes X minute price to the destination. If you don't have enough credit on your account, the call will be denied.

So the solution could be setting the maxDuration to a level you can handle or to make sure you have enough credit on your account and also that PayPal auto top-up is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can see you already added my answer as a comment to your own question, but I'll add it myself anyway for any other person looking for the same question. I'm also adding information on how to set the `maxDuration`.*

When your application makes a PSTN call, our system reserves a sum on your account to make sure you have enough credit to actually pay for the call. If you don’t specify the maximum duration for a call, we reserve 240 minutes X minute price to the destination. If you don't have enough credit on your account, the call will be denied.

- *Suggestion 1: Set maxDuration to a level you can handle (see below for info on setting `maxDuration` from the SDK)*
- *Suggestion 2: Make sure you have enough credit on your account and also that PayPal auto top-up is enabled.*

If you're using one of our SDKs you need to set a callback URL that our service can talk to:

1. Set a callback URL for you application on sinch.com.
2. When a user tries to make a call, we send you a callback to this URL. This callback is called `ICE` (Incoming Call Event) and lets you decide if the call should be allowed or not.
3. You need to answer our callback for the call to go through. The action to send back is called `ConnectPSTN` and you can read more about it here: https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#ConnectPSTNAction Use the `maxDuration` parameter to decide the maximum length a call is allowed.

Comment: we are experiencing a similar problem, what is the root cause of not being able to do Simultaneous PSNT calls (different users)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650788/simultaneous-app-to-phone-calls-with-sinch